# Is my translation right?

Tags: translation

执行总统或国家情报总监指出的其它与影响国家安全情报相关的职责

My translation is,

> "to carry out the other responsibilities that are related to the national safety intelligence that are indicated by the president or the Director of National Intelligence."

Comment: suggestion：安全 （here） security 影响：affect

Comment: The Chinese phrase itself is an ill translation from English.  And I suspect that it is incomplete, esp. concerning the segment "... 其它与 ...".

Answer (score 1):

As @S.Rhee has pointed out, and IMHO, below are some issues with your translation:

- **影响** translates to "affect/influence".
- **安全** in this context translates to "security".
- **职责** translates better to "duties/obligations".
- The second "that" modifying clause should modify **职责**, not **国家安全情报**.

A more accurate translation might be,

> "To carry out the other **duties**, as indicated by the President or the Director of National Intelligence, that are related to **influencing** the National **Security** Intelligence."